# Resize Row Height in Bootstrap 4 on Read More activation (collapse)

Tags: bootstrap-4, row

In a three column row I have created a "read more" setup using Bootstrap's collapse class as such (this is the raw html entered inside a row):

```html
    <div class="blog grid-view col3">
      <div class="blog-posts">
        <div class="isotope row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-view-post">
            <div class="post">
              <figure>
                <a href="../../our-work/independent/bebc/">
                  <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="info"><span>View Project</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <img src="../../wp-content/uploads/2020/05/002-ATKINS_1240x914_.jpg"
                    class="attachment-ryla-grid size-ryla-grid wp-post-image"
                    alt=""
                    height="300"
                    width="440">
                </a>
              </figure>
              <div class="post-content">
                <h3 class="post-title"><a href="../../our-work/independent/bebc/">Business
                    Entrepreneurship Boot Camp</a></h3>
                <div class="meta"> </div>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum quad est felito que nuncan pare neque porro
                  quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
                  consectetur, adipisci velit…<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rm_bebc" class="btn">Read
                    More</a>
                    <span id="rm_bebc" class="collapse">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                                    </span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-view-post">
            <div class="post">
              <figure> <a href="../../our-work/independent/nftp/">
                  <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="info"><span>View Project</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <img src="../../wp-content/uploads/2020/05/022-FAREWELL_1240x914.jpg"
                    class="attachment-ryla-grid size-ryla-grid wp-post-image"
                    alt=""
                    height="300"
                    width="440">
                </a> </figure>
              <div class="post-content">
                <h3 class="post-title"><a href="../../our-work/independent/nftp/">Netherlands
                    Fulbright Teachers Program</a></h3>
                <div class="meta"> </div>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum quad est felito que nuncan pare neque porro
                  quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
                  consectetur, adipisci velit…<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rm_nftp" class="exp_col">
                  Read More</a>
                    <span id="rm_nftp" class="collapse">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                                    </span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-view-post">
            <div class="post">
              <figure> <a href="../../our-work/independent/step-up/" target="_blank">
                  <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="info"><span>View Project</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <img src="../../wp-content/uploads/2020/05/suu_logo_1240x914_.jpg"
                    class="attachment-ryla-grid size-ryla-grid wp-post-image"
                    alt=""
                    height="300"
                    width="440">
                </a> </figure>
              <div class="post-content">
                <h3 class="post-title"><a href="../../our-work/independent/step-up/"
                    target="_blank">Step
                    Up</a></h3>
                <div class="meta"> </div>
                <p>STEP-UP stands for Sustain, Train, Educate and Promote in
                  Uganda. STEP-UP is an ITD project which offers medical and and
                  psycho-social…<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rm_su">Read More</a>
                    <span id="rm_su" class="collapse">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                                    </span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What I want is a function that will increase the height of the row when one of the "Read More" links is activated; and decrease it once I add a "Read Less" option.

I have had trouble finding an appropriate javascript function for this. I do not have the permissions to add new binaries to the system.

Comment: Please post the all of the relevant code (to reproduce the issue) in the question instead of linking to an external site that will change in time and make the question irrelevant to future readers

Comment: I have updated the code as requested

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all I had to do was break the three `<div class="post">` sections up and put each into it's own bootstrap column - the columns expanded on their own!